# Android image comparison by pixel

Tags: android

I am trying to Math any random image which is captured by my camera. I want to do comparision between them and I want to give rating of that out of 10.

I am using this but it is not working:

```
     bMap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/mahendra.jpeg");
     bMap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/google.jpg");
     System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>"+bMap1+"and"+bMap2);

     //image.setImageBitmap(bMap);

     BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
     opt.inSampleSize = 5;


     int intColor1 = 0;
     int intColor2 = 0;
     for (int x = 0; x <  bMap1.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <  bMap1.getHeight(); y++) {
             intColor1 =  bMap1.getPixel(x, y);
             intColor2 = bMap2.getPixel(x, y); 
             //System.out.print(" ("+ x + ","+ y +") c:" + intColor1);   
        }
        String resultString = String.valueOf(intColor1);

     }
     //now calculate percentage difference
     double razlika = (((double)intColor1 - intColor2)/intColor2)*100;
     System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+razlika);

      if(razlika<100)
      {
          System.out.println(">>>>>>>>Rating of your image is 1 out of 10");

      }
```

Comment: What part is "not working"? Does it not do what you expect it to? Do you get an exception? An error?

Comment: hey Have you seen Ugly meter application I am developing application like that i have capture the image now i want tocompare this image with one of my perfect image by pixel and i want to give rating this captured image Out of 10 .If this  is less it means you are less ugly and and more its means you are too much ugly ...If you have any idea about it please give me......

Comment: please give me a answer of my problem..........

Comment: And you still have not said what the problem with the code was..

Comment: no problem in my code but it gives me only percentage but can you give how can i give a logic for rating the image......